# Pandas groupby TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following code:

```
group = df.groupby(['Id',  'Name'])
conditions = [
    ((group["Balance"]>0) & (group['Value']>0) & (group['L_Date']<=group['c_date'])),
    ((group["Balance"]==0) & (group['Value']==0) & (group['L_Date']<=group['c_date']))]
choices = ['Good', 'Bad']
df['outcome'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Normal')
```

But it is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'int'
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you paste snippet of input and expected output data in the question as text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no reason use `groupby`, because in code are not count some values per groups.

```
group = df.groupby(['Id',  'Name'])
```

Use only:

```
conditions = [
    ((df["Balance"]>0) & (df['Value']>0) & (df['L_Date']<=df['c_date'])),
    ((df["Balance"]==0) & (df['Value']==0) & (df['L_Date']<=df['c_date']))]
choices = ['Good', 'Bad']
df['outcome'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Normal')
```